# why except doesn't work properly ? (newbie)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Building a JSON, I have no need for the ":new" and ":edit/:id" routes .
So I asked rails to do not create those but when I specify the routes which should not be routable (with Be_routable matcher)...it doesn't work.
Any suggestions please ?

**routes.rb :**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :todos, :except => [:edit, :new]
end
```

**routes_spec.rb :**

```
require 'spec_helper'


RSpec.describe "routes for Todos", :type => :routing do


  it "routes get /todos to the todos controller index action" do
    expect(:get => "/todos").
      to route_to(:controller => "todos", :action => "index")
  end


  it "routes post /todos to the todos controller create action" do
    expect(:post => "/todos").
      to route_to(:controller => "todos", :action => "create")
  end


  it "routes get /todos/:id to the todos controller show action" do
    expect(:get => "/todos/:id").
      to route_to(:controller => "todos", :action => "show", :id => ":id")
  end


  it "routes patch /todos/:id to the todos controller update action" do
    expect(:patch => "/todos/:id").
      to route_to(:controller => "todos", :action => "update", :id => ":id")
  end

  it "routes put /todos/:id to the todos controller update action" do
    expect(:put => "/todos/:id").
      to route_to(:controller => "todos", :action => "update", :id => ":id")
  end


  it "routes delete /todos/:id to the todos controller delete action" do
    expect(:delete => "/todos/:id").
      to route_to(:controller => "todos", :action => "destroy", :id => ":id")
  end


  it "does not route to /todos/new" do
    expect(:get => "/todos/new").not_to be_routable 
  end
end
```

the last it block throw this error :

```
Failures:

1) routes for Todos does not route to /todos/new
   Failure/Error: expect(:get => "/todos/new").not_to be_routable
     expected {:get=>"/todos/new"} not to be routable, but it routes to {:controller=>"todos", :action=>"show", :id=>"new"}
   # ./spec/routing/routes_spec.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

all the other it blocks are OK

**todos_controller.rb :**

```
class TodosController < ActionController::API


  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :not_found


  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)

    if @todo.save
      render json: @todo, status: :created, location: @todo
    else
      render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end


  def show
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    render json: @todo, status: :ok, location: @todo
  end


  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
    render json: @todos, status: :ok #, location: @todos DOESN'T WORK 'location:' OPTION
  end


  def  update
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])

    if @todo.update(todo_params)
      render json: @todo, status: :ok, location: @todo
    else
      render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @todo = Todo.destroy(params[:id])
    render json: @todo, status: :no_content, location: @todo
  end


  private

    def todo_params
      params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :content)
    end

    def not_found(e)
      render :json => { :message => e.message }, :status => :not_found
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because you cannot use this test.

The reason is this route:

> /todos/:id

is the route that routes to the SHOW action.

So when you browse to

> /todos/new

the value of ':id' will be 'new'.

You can check this by adding 'puts params[:id]' in the show method, then in the browser goto '/todos/new' and you will see in the log that it will display 'new'.

You should probably add a route constraint. For example:

```
get   'todos/:id'   => 'todos#show', constraint: { id: /\d+/ }
```

More info [here](https://blog.8thlight.com/ben-voss/2013/01/12/how-to-use-rails-route-constraints.html) which I *strongly* advise you to read and understand. :)

EDIT: The constraint restricts the param :id so that only integers are allowed.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: problem isn't solved yet. even with the constraint you gave me...I still have the same error. I'm digging deeper.

Comment: ok, but you do realise that the test you are running will never pass? it will always match the show route. You need to write a different test

Comment: OK, So how can I test that route isn't routable or doesn't exist ? can you give me some insights to do it please ?

Comment: The route does exist, so you cannot test that it does not.  You should replace it with another test for the show route to test the constraint - so add a test that checks that the show route only accepts an integer id.

Comment: If this post has answered your question and helped solve the problem, please mark it as answer. This allows others to see what helps if they have the same problem in the future (and it gives me points, rewarding me for my time and effort). Thanks.